# rpm reinstall does not reinstall config files?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec, zypper

I have an rpm with a file marked as config file in the %files section:

```
%files
%config /path/to/file.conf
```

now suppose I edit this file on-disk. I wish to repair this and redo a clean install of the package; thus restoring the config file to its original state; using

```
zypper in -f my-package
```

after doing this; the config file is still in its edited version. If it was not a **reinstall** but an **update** (with an rpm containing a changed version!); then rpm would have moved my edited file to /path/to/file.conf.rpmsave and reinstalled the new one.

What are my options to circumvent this problem? Is this normal behavior? If I was using rpm; I suppose I could use `rpm -if my-package.rpm --replacefiles`; but that option does not exist for zypper.

PS I use [this page](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes zypper would need to add --replacefiles in order to overwrite %config files. The harder issue (for zypper) is the scope of --replacefiles: the option applies to a transaction, not a single package in the transaction.

Easiest solution by far (imho) is to install the package manually using --replacefiles on the CLI.

Comment: helpful; but not a real solution :) For the moment I am considering just removing the `%config` tag for the config files that I want to be sure to replace with their package version upon install...

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `rpmconf -a` to handle updating config files. However, I ran into a similar issue after accidentally keeping a config file I wanted to replace. The rpmnew file is then deleted and, as you also noticed, `zypper in -f` will not place it back.

I got around the issue by simply deleting the config file and running the zypper command again.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are seeing the difference between `%config` and `%config(noreplace)`. However, even if it doesn't replace, I think it *should* export it as `file.conf.rpmnew`.

You can always use `rpm2cpio` to extract the original file if you *really* need it.

Comment: you didn't read the page I referenced I think: I'm in the case `%config` , changed in update RPM (although I think rpm doesn't notice that due to reinstall), so he should use "File from update, edited file in .rpmsave"

Comment: and after the `zypper in -f` there is no rpmnew NOR rpmsave file.